# multiple condition variables in c

Tags: c, pthreads

I am developing an application in C where in thread **A** have to wait for three events(like reception of data) from 3 different threads namely **B, C, D**. I am able to implement for a single event using **pthread_cond_wait**, **pthread_cond_signal** and **mutex** but I want to expand this concept to multiple events using single condition variable and single mutex. Can somebody please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a semaphore. But your question is both too broad and also lacking in specific details so is difficult to answer.

Comment: Producer-consumer queue.

Comment: Pretty clear to me what was being asked.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really nothing tricky to it: presuming for one event you have code in thread A like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
while (!event_b_pending)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);

/* Process Event B */
```

with code in thread B like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
event_b_pending = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Then for three events, you would change thread A to:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
while (!event_b_pending && !event_c_pending && !event_d_pending)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);

if (event_b_pending)
{
    /* Process Event B */
}

if (event_c_pending)
{
    /* Process Event C */
}

if (event_d_pending)
{
    /* Process Event D */
}
```

with threads C and D working like thread B (except setting the appropriate flag).

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me a lot